# VIiew in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with postresql view. I did a view that takes information from 2 tables. One has their names, their number and their phone number recorded, and the other records their home address, work address, email, date of creation, address type 1 and 2 dependent addresses whether it is business or home and other such things. I did get a view but it shows me all the information.

If one client has entered 20 business and home addresses, then 20 business addresses will come out as well, and I want to show me the last business address and the last home address that the given client entered. If I have 3 clients with 5 work and home addresses, I want to give me each client the last home and work address.

Comment: Please show us the code of the view (or a simplified version of it), along with the result it produces, and the result that you would expect, as text (no images).

Answer (score 0):

If you want one record per client, then `distinct on` comes to mind.  Something like this:

```
select distinct on (client_id) t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     using (client_id)
order by cllient_id, t2.created_at desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

-- View: public.vi_a

```
-- DROP VIEW public.vi_a;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.vi_a AS
 SELECT pmc.employee_id AS "FF",
    pmc.first,
    pmc.surname,
    ppa.address_1,
    ppa.address_2,
    ppa.date,
    ppa.address_type,
    ppa.employee
   FROM a pmc
     LEFT JOIN b ppa ON pmc.employee_id = ppa.employee;

ALTER TABLE public.vi_a
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

So I create a view

Only things in the red dependent type, whether 1 or 2, should appear in the view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zSTA.jpg)